# pandas.Timedelta with BusinessDay

Tags: python, pandas

I need to apply a pd.Timedelta offset to an index but I would like to take into consideration only business days. Unfortunately this is not possible as pd.Timedelta doesn't support business days at the moment.

Input:

```
>>> d = pd.date_range(start='2015-1-10', end='2015-1-22', freq='B')
DatetimeIndex(['2015-01-12', '2015-01-13', '2015-01-14', '2015-01-15',
               '2015-01-16', '2015-01-19', '2015-01-20', '2015-01-21',
               '2015-01-22'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='B')

>>> td = pd.Timedelta('2D3h')
Timedelta('2 days 03:00:00')
```

Expected output:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2015-01-14 03:00:00', '2015-01-15 03:00:00',
               '2015-01-16 03:00:00', '2015-01-19 03:00:00',
               '2015-01-20 03:00:00', '2015-01-21 03:00:00',
               '2015-01-22 03:00:00', '2015-01-23 03:00:00',
               '2015-01-26 03:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='B')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a possible solution:

```
def add_bday_timedelta(input, timedelta):
    """
    Add timedelta to input taking into consideration business days
    """
    days = timedelta.components.days
    offset = timedelta - '%dD' % days
    return input + BusinessDay(days) + offset

>>> add_bday_timedelta(d, td)
DatetimeIndex(['2015-01-14 03:00:00', '2015-01-15 03:00:00',
               '2015-01-16 03:00:00', '2015-01-19 03:00:00',
               '2015-01-20 03:00:00', '2015-01-21 03:00:00',
               '2015-01-22 03:00:00', '2015-01-23 03:00:00',
               '2015-01-26 03:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='B')
```